# Site loading sequence reg

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I've a login form of a website running IIS/Asp.net which during booking times because extremely sluggish.

At the LOGIN PAGE I'm doing:

```
$("#submit1").trigger('click') //this will login into PAGE1 using form.submit()

setTimeout(function(){
window.location = "/PAGE2";
},500);
```

PAGE1 has a GET link to PAGE2.

All I want to know whether it will take me to PAGE2 or PAGE1 ?

Because the IIS server will first process the form submission and send the PAGE1 content. Then it will send the GET request PAGE2 content.

How will the browser(Chrome & Firefox) behave? If it first received the POST response then will it discard the PAGE2 GET response?

Or will it overwrite the POST response(PAGE1) with the GET response(PAGE2)

Assuming POST response(PAGE1) is received and now site is showing PAGE1. After 1 minute the GET response(PAGE2) is received. Now what will the browser do?

I want to depict the sequence(which is example case):
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Your code, timer included, gets destroyed when another page is loaded. What are the URLs of the login page, page 1 and 2?

Comment: @wOxxOm The login page is at bit.ly/2s7Kc3K  .But what happens if the form submission response is received after timer is executed? On the contrary I've checked the code when site is not slow at all. It's directly taking me to PAGE2

Answer (score 1):

### The code

```
$("#submit1").trigger('click') //this will login into PAGE1

setTimeout(function(){
window.location = "/PAGE2";
},500);
```

This will trigger the click event on the element with id `submit1`. Assume it is a button for login.

## Then

There are 2 possibilities because you didn't mentioned whether this is carried out via Ajax or not.

1. If you used ajax, then if the login process completed within 500mS, then you will successfully log in to `PAGE1` and redirect to `PAGE2`. Because it is ajax.
2. If you didn't used ajax, then the code

   setTimeout(function(){
   window.location = "/PAGE2";
   },500);

will be ignored. Because at the first event itself, it will take you to `PAGE1`and the life cycle of this script from `Login Page` will end. So, you won't get to `PAGE2`. If you want to go to `PAGE2`, then you should add the above mentioned code in `PAGE1`.

## Note

The request GET and POST can't do anything with the life cycle of a script if it is not made via Ajax.

## Update

No. Both POST and GET won't trigger at a time.

First the POST will trigger.

> If it first received the POST response then will it discard the PAGE2 GET response?

Yes

Because the GET request is made from login page and as a result of the POST message, you are already redirected to Page1. So, the GET response won't even catch by the browser.

Comment: There is no Ajax. Thanks but  your answer but I'll be happy if there is good technical justification

Comment: That's all I need to know. Will give you a good answer tomorrow. At present answer, from point 2. Will be applicable for you

Answer (score 1):

in other words what i understand your question is "which page will my browser load?"

The broswer will Load whatever the most recent request it makes.

if your button click request longer than 500 miliseconds to load a new page resource the button click request should get overwritten to load page 2.  If the page loads before 500 miliseconds then it should load page 1.. its a bit like asking what happens if i type www.google.com in my address bar press enter and then enter www.facebook.com... which resource do you think will load?... The most recent request that you make.

By the way window.location = '...' will do a server request just like your asp button click does.

I recomend that you open up google chrome network tab and investigate/observe what calls you make to the server in what sequence...